# Empty elements in an input form passed on to URL

Tags: python, html, forms, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent submitting the HTML form’s input field value if it empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty)

If I have a three piece input form and a submit button.

Form 1 id: book
Form 2 id: music
Form 3 id: tv

Say I put "Book1" in the book field, "Music1" in the music field and nothing in the TV field, I would get this URL:

```
http://url/search/?book=Book1&music=Music1&tv=
```

What happens is that even though there is nothing in the "tv" field, "&tv=" still gets appended to the URL. Is there any way to stop this, or is this standard browser behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the browsers behavior, as correctly said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12913421/447356).

To "overcome" this default behavior, you will have to use client side scripting. Most simple and unintrusive way I can think of is to add this on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        var oForm = document.forms[i];
        oForm.onsubmit = function() {
            for (var j = 0; j < this.elements.length; j++) {
                var element = this.elements[j];
                if (element.type === "text" && element.value === "")
                    element.disabled = true;
            }
        };
    }
};​
</script>
```

This will automatically disable any empty text boxes when submitting a form, causing the browser to not send any value for them.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wUenh/).

Answer (score 1):

This is standard and logical behavior. "No value" is not the same as "empty value".