# Submit only non empty fields from Form

Tags: javascript, forms

That is the form:

```html
<form action="" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="para1">
  <input type="text" name="para2">
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Now when I fill out only the first field I get **example.com/?para1=value&para2=**
But I just want it to be **example.com/?para1=value** because para2 don't contains value. How can I do this? Should be possible with JS or anything?

Comment: on submit remove the empty elements

Comment: using js, set the disabled property (disabled form elements do not post back) e.g. `'$('##').prop(disabled, true);` but better to handle this in your controller/action method

Comment: I only know PHP could you give me a full code please?

Comment: @EddyUnruh Don't you see my answer below?

Comment: I see but still have a problem with the ? at the end by submitting empty form. When there will be no solution then I will accept your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent submitting the HTML form's input field value if it empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this,

Include jQuery and use following snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $("input").each(function(index, obj){
            if($(obj).val() == "") {
                $(obj).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats nice but I still always get the ? after submiting so: example.com? is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: What I need is when a user is on example.com?para=value and he try to remove it by submiting empty field he should get example.com but he gets example.com?

Comment: Personally I would set the attr `name` to empty, because when the user submits the page it may flicker and so on. With an empty name, it won't appear in the request either.

Comment: @Wouter0100 Good idea. Appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would be the plain javascript version:

```
<form id="theform" action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return removeEmpties()">
    <input type="text" name="para1"/>
    <input type="text" name="para2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
<script>
  function removeEmpties() {
        var form = document.getElementById("theform");
        var inputs = form.children;
        var remove = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].value == "") {
                remove.push(inputs[i]);
            }
        }

        if(remove.length == inputs.length - 1)
          return false;

        for(var i = 0; i < remove.length; i++) 
          form.removeChild(remove[i]);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works too but there is still left the ? when I submit empty fields, it can't be avoided?

Comment: I guess you could prevent the form submitting if there was no input filled out -- see example above.

Answer (score 0):

put onclick on submit button to call submitFunc()   , rather than use form action:

```
<input type="button" onClick="submitFunc();" value="Pass Parameters"/>
```

js functions:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function submitFunc()
{
   loopRemove("text",3);
   document.testform.action = "file:///C:/Users/mwafi/Desktop/test.html";
   document.testform.submit();
}

function loopRemove(startName,count)
{
  for(var i=1;i<=count;i++)
  {
    if(document.getElementById(startName+i).value=="")
    {
        var t = document.getElementById(startName+i);
        t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
    }
  }  
}

</script>
```

full code with HTML form:

```
<html>

<title>Pass non-empty parameters</title>

<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function submitFunc()
{
   loopRemove("text",3);
   document.testform.action = "http://www.google.com/";
   document.testform.submit();
}

function loopRemove(startName,count)
{
  for(var i=1;i<=count;i++)
  {
    if(document.getElementById(startName+i).value=="")
    {
        var t = document.getElementById(startName+i);
        t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
    }
  }  
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="document.testform.reset();">

 <form name="testform">

  <h3>Pass Non-empty parameters</h3>

  Parameter 1 : <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" /><br>
  Parameter 2 : <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" /><br>
  Parameter 3 : <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" /><br><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="submitFunc();" value="Pass Parameters"/>

 <form>

</body>

</html>
```

remember don't use form action.

source: http://www.scriptsplash.com/2009/07/passing-only-non-empty-fields-on-form.html

Comment: What would be the benefit not to using form action? SEO? document.testform.action = "file:///C:/Users/mwafi/Desktop/test.html"; wouldn't work its an rewritten php file