# Avoid passing empty form fields using get method

Tags: html

Let's say we have a simple form:

```
<form method="get">
  <input type="text" name="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="bar" />
  <input type="text" name="buz" />
</form>
```

If we post it without setting any values, it redirects us to:

```
?foo=&bar=&buz=
```

If we set only `bar` value to `SO`, the result is:

```
?foo=&bar=SO&buz=
```

Is it possible to force somehow without JavaScript (especially without any jQuery plugin ;-)) to skip empty values, to get in the second case only:

```
?bar=SO
```

Comment: not that I know of, because an empty value is very different from no value.

Comment: without javascript... or jquery.... boy you are really tying our hands here :P

Comment: Nope, they are going to submit regardless, best best is either JS it or have a processing component build the url based on submitted values and redirect.

Comment: there's a discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty/64029534#64029534 which was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Without JavaScript, you can't prevent those empty fields being submitted.

(If your life depends on having the URL `?bar=SO` arrive at the server, you could have the server detect empty values, strip them and issue a redirect, but that's horrible.)