# How not to send empty input value in GET-query

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form like this

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="order_by" value="">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It has some jQuery handlers to fill in "`order_by`" field.
If I submit this form with empty "`order_by`" filed, I get an address like this: `index.php?id=1&order_by=`

What is the best way I can do to get following address after form submission if the "`order_by`" is empty: `index.php?id=1` ?

Comment: What are you using exactly for form submission?

Comment: On submit, check if it's empty and, if it is, remove it from the DOM.

Comment: I don't use JavaScript for submission, just clean html form behaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent submitting the HTML form's input field value if it empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty)

Answer (score 10):

you can disable empty fields so they don't get added as data

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var emptyinputs = $(this).find('input').filter(function(){
        return !$.trim(this.value).length;  // get all empty fields
    }).prop('disabled',true);    
});
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that truly answers the OP's question, which was how to not set the empty values in the first place. I had the same problem, where I didn't want the URL to get polluted with optional fields from a search form. This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

in php you can do like this

```
if(!isset($_GET['order_by']) || !$_GET['order_by'])
    return 'error msg';
```

or

```
if(empty($_GET['order_by']))
    return 'error msg';
```

change html like this

```
   <form action="index.php" method="get" onsubmit="return valid()">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="order_by" id="order_by" value="">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

javascript:

```
  function valid(){
   if(!$('#order_by').val()){
       alert("Order by not found");
       return false;
    }
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: I need to avoid initialization of $_GET['order_by'] if it's empty in form, not it's validation at php level.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form#formID').submit(function(e){
     var emptyinputs = $(this).find('select').filter(function(){
     return !$.trim(this.value).length;  
    }).prop('disabled',true);    

     var emptyinputs = $(this).find('input').filter(function(){
     return !$.trim(this.value).length;  
    }).prop('disabled',true);    
});
```

You can disable empty fields (both select and input) so they don't get added as data, and for a custom form id.