# In a Django template, how to specify a dictionary key which is itself an attribute?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django project with a `ListView` that has both a search form, known in the view's context as `search_form`, and a filter form, `filter_form`. The interface looks like this:

[image]

Both the `search_form` and the `filter_form` ultimately change what is returned by the `ListView`'s [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method. I would like to make it such that when you first apply a filter and then do a search, it will search the filtered results.

At the moment, the 'reverse' functionality has already been implemented: when you first search and then filter, it will filter the search results. This is because of a hidden `input` element in the `filter_form`:

```
<form action={% url 'dashboard:families' %} method="GET" data-behavior="filters">
                <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q.strip }}"/>

                <div class="input-field col s2">
                  {{ filter_form.guide }}
                  <label class="active">Guide</label>
                  {% if filter_form.is_guide_filled %}
                    <a href="" class="clear"><i class="material-icons tiny">clear</i></a>
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
```

For comparison, the search bar has the following template, `_search.html`:

```
<form action="{% url action %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the main list view, `index.html`, the search template is included like so:

```
{% block search_form %}
  {% with action='dashboard:families' placeholder='Search Families' %}
    {% include '_search.html' %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

In order to make the search form persist the filters, I've noticed that for the `guide` field only, the following works:

```
<input type="hidden" name="guide" value="{{ request.GET.guide }}"/>
```

I would like to generalize this to include all the filters. I've tried the following:

```
  {% if filter_form %}
    {% for field in filter_form %}
      {% with field_name=field.name %}
        <input type="hidden" name=field_name value="{{ request.GET.field_name}}"/>
      {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

However, if I try this I literally get "field_name" in the querystring:

[image]

As I understand from the [DTL docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language), the dot-notation implements dictionary lookup, attribute lookup, and list-index lookup. If I were to try something like

```
request.GET.field.name
```

it would probably try to look up "field" in the `request.GET` dictionary-like object and not find anything. In regular Python, what I'd essentially like to do is

```
request.GET[field.name]
```

I thought I could make this work with a `with` block, but apparently this doesn't work. Any advice on how to implement this?

**Update**

If I specify the `name` attribute for the `input` element as `"{{field_name}}"` instead of just `field_name`, like so,

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{field_name}}" value="{{ request.GET.field_name}}"/>
```

The problem is that the `value` is being set to an empty string instead of the desired value, which leads to a `ValueError` for the `guide` field (which is a `ModelChoiceField` expecting an integer as input):

[image]

Why is the attribute lookup not working in this case?

**Update 2**

Responding to Lemayzeur's comment, the full traceback is:

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/two_factor/views/mixins.py" in dispatch
  82.         return super(OTPRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  56.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  92.         return super(PermissionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/views/families.py" in get
  74.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/views/base.py" in get
  111.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/views/base.py" in get
  74.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get
  160.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/views/families.py" in get_queryset
  122.             queryset = queryset.filter(lucy_guide__in=guide)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  784.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  802.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1250.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1276.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1206.             condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  24.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  56.                 self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in <listcomp>
  56.                 self.rhs = [target_field.get_prep_value(v) for v in self.rhs]

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  966.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard/families
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

If I set a trace in the view's `get_queryset()` method, just before 122 in the stack trace, I see that `guide` is indeed an empty list containing an empty string, as it is in `self.request.GET`:

```
> /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web/dashboard/views/families.py(121)get_queryset()
    120 
--> 121         if guide:
    122             queryset = queryset.filter(lucy_guide__in=guide)

ipdb> guide
['']

ipdb> self.request.GET
<QueryDict: {'q': ['Christine'], 'status': [''], 'next_outreach': [''], 'country': [''], 'vip': [''], 'app': [''], 'guide': [''], 'package': ['']}>
```

Aside from the difficulties in submitting the empty value, I actually would expect the `guide` field of `request.GET` to have a non-empty value here. For example, if I return to the 'simplified' version of the hidden filter form, with only the `guide` field:

```
<form action="{% url action %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="guide" value="{{ request.GET.guide }}"/>
</form>
```

Then I select a filter, and enter a search term in the search bar:

[image]

Then when I set a trace just after the view's `get` method, like so:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

I do see that both `q` and `guide` are in `request.GET`:

```
ipdb> request.GET
<QueryDict: {'q': ['Christine'], 'guide': ['6']}>
```

So in the 'general' form with `request.GET.field_name`, I would also expect the `request.GET` to look like this, with also empty lists for the other fields. It seems like the Django Template Language's dot notation is trying to literally do a dictionary or attribute lookup for `'field_name'` and not finding anything; perhaps I should write a custom filter as described in [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable) to perform the dictionary lookup of `field.name`?

Comment: I think you should have `name={{field_name}}` instead of `name=field_name` there: `<input type="hidden" name=field_name value="`  we access variables in template with `{{ }}`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix the 'keys' but I'm still getting a `ValueError` for the `guide` field: apparently `request.GET.field_name` is not equivalent to `request.GET.guide`?

Comment: obviously, it will be empty, because when you set your form,  'with the `loop` there're no values for them... . rather than that, try {{field.value}} if you had set value from the form

Comment: In the picture where we have the traceback, which action trigger this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by writing a custom `get` filter as described in [Django template how to look up a dictionary value with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000022/django-template-how-to-look-up-a-dictionary-value-with-a-variable):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

I updated `_search.html` as follows:

```
{% load get %}

<form action="{% url action %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
  {% if filter_form %}
    {% for field in filter_form %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ field.name }}" value="{{ request.GET|get:field.name }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Now, if I try to search a filtered result, it works as expected:

[image]

Note that this also works fine for the filters that are not applied - these have the value `None` instead of an empty string - without any need to filter them out in the form.

Answer (score 1):

So it basically boils down to *not submitting keys in the GET request that have an empty string value*. This appears to be unsupported natively in HTML; you need some JS magic to make this happen. See this thread: [How to prevent submitting the HTML form's input field value if it empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029532/how-to-prevent-submitting-the-html-forms-input-field-value-if-it-empty)

However, a pure Django solution would be to modify your filter dict to exclude keys that are null. I am not sure how you are filtering this in Django, but assuming you have override the `get_queryset` method; you can always do:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(YourView, self).get_queryset()
    filters = {k, v for k, v in request.GET.items() if v != ''}  # Be as generic/specific as needed here for exclusion
    qs = qs.filter(**filters)  # Fire your filtering logic here; this is a sample
    return qs
```

Comment: this is totally what he's asking for, take a look at the update of the question.. you ask a question in your answer, this should be a comment

Comment: Ah; missed the update entirely; my bad. Sure, will ask questions in comments.

Comment: Aside from the issue of filtering out null values from the form, in the described situation I actually would not expect the `guide` field to be null in the first place; see my updated question.