# How to preserve the existing query string when submitting a form in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a `ListView` which contains both a filter form and search form as described in [In a Django template, how to specify a dictionary key which is itself an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161510/in-a-django-template-how-to-specify-a-dictionary-key-which-is-itself-an-attribu). When I submit a search query, I would like it to retain the existing filter query.

Previously, I implemented this by adding hidden `<input>` elements of which the `value` was obtained from `request.GET` using a custom filter, `get`, which calls the `QueryDict`'s `get` method. I found that the problem with this is that for `MultipleChoiceField`s, for example, if multiple choices are selected, only one is retained, since the `get` method only returns the *last* value as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get.

I'm now trying a different approach. Using the custom filter `relative_url`,

```
from django import template
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.http import QueryDict

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def relative_url(field_name, value, query_string=None):
    """
    Replace the key 'field_name' in the query_string with the given value.
    For example,

    relative_url('guide', 1, 'q=Christine') == '?q=Christine&guide=1'

    (After https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/snippet/2016/08/22/dealing-with-querystring-parameters.html)
    """
    url = urlencode({field_name: value})
    if query_string:
        query_dict = QueryDict(query_string, mutable=True)
        query_dict[field_name] = value
        url = query_dict.urlencode()
    return '?' + url
```

and the custom filter `referer_query`,

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def referer_query(request):
    return urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')).query
```

I've tried to modify the search form as follows:

```
{% load relative_url %}
{% load referer_query %}


<form action="{% relative_url "q" search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' request|referer_query %}" method="get" class="left search col s6 hide-on-small-and-down" novalidate>
  <div class="input-field">
    <input id="search" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}"
        autocomplete="off" type="search" name="q"
        value="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}"
        data-query="{{ search_form.q.value.strip|default:'' }}">
    <label for="search" class="active"><i class="material-icons search-icon">search</i></label>
    <i data-behavior="search-clear"
        class="material-icons search-icon"
        {% if not search_form.q.value %}style="display: none;"{% endif %}>close</i>
  </div>
</form>
```

There is some Javascript code which submits the form when you press Enter (without having to press a submit button):

```
  $(document).on('click', '[data-behavior="search-clear"]', function(e) {
    $('#search').val('').parents('form').submit();
  });

  $(function() {
    setSearchClearVisibility($('#search'));
  });

  $(document).on('keydown', '#search', function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      setSearchClearVisibility($el);
    }, 10);
  });

  function setSearchClearVisibility(el) {
    if (el.val() === '') {
      $('[data-behavior="search-clear"]').hide();
    } else {
      $('[data-behavior="search-clear"]').show();
    }
  }

  $(document).on('keydown', '#search', function(e) {
    var $el = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (e.keyCode !== 27) return;

      $('#search').val('').blur();
      setSearchClearVisibility($el);

      if ($el.data('query') !== '') {
        $('#search').parents('form').submit();
      }
    }, 10);
  });
```

The problem is that when I try this out by a selecting a filter and entering a search query as illustrated below,

[image]

when I drop into the debugger in the view's `get` method, I see that `request.GET` only contains the search query, not the filter queries, despite that `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` does show the filter queries:

```
ipdb> request.GET
<QueryDict: {'q': ['Christine']}>
ipdb> request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
'http://localhost:8000/dashboard/families?q=&guide=6&guide=4&next_outreach=&vip=&app='
```

In short, it seems that `request.GET` is determined only by the `<input>` elements in the form, and not by the form's `action`, which contains additional query parameters.

How can I make the `request.GET` include the query contained by the `HTTP_REFERER`?

(I've noticed that this [blog post](http://www.iovene.com/posts/2012/02/manipulating-the-url-query-string-with-django-and-multiplechoicefields/) describes a solution to a similar problem, but the code snippet looks a bit spaghetti-like and I think there must be a simpler way).

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem by including a hidden `filter_form` in the `search_form`. So in `_search.html`, within the `<form>` tags, I added

```
  {% for field in filter_form %}
    {{ field.as_hidden }}
  {% endfor %}
```

This makes use of the [`as_hidden`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5e06fa1469180909c51c07151692412269e51ea3/django/forms/forms.py#L582) property of the field.